# db_select query advice

Tags: database

I have two content types: **development** and **house**.

A **development** has many **house**s.

Each **house** has a *house_type* field

I'm trying to perform a db_select query that allows me to search all developments and find the *house_type*s attached to them.

I've managed to find the developments, then found the attached *houses_on_development* (i've used group_concat for this), ***AND THEN, WHERE I'M STUCK...***

I need to query each of the *house_type*s of these concatenated house_ids individually to find out their *house_type*.

I've started with:

```
$search_type = 'development';
$query = db_select('node', 'development');
$query->condition('development.status', '1', '=');

 $query->leftjoin('field_data_belongs2dev', 'property',
        'development.nid = property.field_data_belongs2dev_target_id');
$query->addExpression('group_concat(property.entity_id)', 'houses_on_development');
```

And now i'm stuck.  I know how to write the query to get the house_types if I was querying house_id one at a time but don't know how to fit that query into a bigger db_select.  For this I would use:

```
SELECT field_property_type_tid
   FROM field_data_field_property_type
   WHERE entity_id
   IN  ( house_id1, house_id2, etc... )
```

I feel like i'm so close but missing that final bit od knowledge.  Please help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at entity field queries, rather then db_queries. Entity field queries are designed to do just this https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

Answer (score 0):

Think your query needs to be:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'development');
$query->fields('property_type', array('field_property_type_tid'))
  ->condition('development.status', 1, '=')
  ->addJoin('LEFT', 'field_data_belongs2dev', 'property', 'development.nid = property.field_data_belongs2dev_target_id');
$query->addJoin('LEFT', 'field_data_field_property_type', 'property_type', 'property.field_data_belongs2dev_target_id = property_type.entity_id');
$query->addExpression('group_concat(property.entity_id)', 'houses_on_development');
$results = $query->execute();
```

Hope this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, however, this seems to product the same result i've already got. That is a comma separated list of house IDs.  I then need to query the 'proerties ids to get the houuse type id

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, maybe a fuller explanation would help